# Can we create an IIB(Instance Initialization Block) inside a method? If we can't why It's not giving compile time error?

Tags: java

Friends I'm confused, while coding I accidentally an opening and closing curly brackets came inside a method

```
List<EmpQualificationLevelTo> fixedTOs = employeeInfoFormNew.getEmployeeInfoTONew().getEmpQualificationFixedTo();
if(fixedTOs != null && !fixedTOs.isEmpty())
{
    Iterator<EmpQualificationLevelTo> it = fixedTOs.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        EmpQualificationLevelTo fixedTO = it.next();
        FormFile eduDoc = fixedTO.getEducationDoc();
        if((eduDoc != null && eduDoc.getFileName() != null && !eduoc.getFileName().isEmpty()) && (fixedTO.getQualification() != null && !fixedTO.getQualification().isEmpty())) {
            errors.add("error", new ActionError( "knoledgepro.employee.education.uploadWithoutQualification"));
        }
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You can see that below the **if-block** inside the **while-loop**. Can anybody help, why it is not giving any compile time error or what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an [instance initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-InstanceInitializer). Instance initializers are declared in a class or enum body, not within methods.

This is just an empty [block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2): unnecessary, but still legal.

Empty blocks and empty statements can be safely removed:

```
{
    ;
    ;;
    //this block compiles successfully
    ;{} 
}
```

**[UPDATE]:** Technically, blocks can be used to separate scopes. For example:

```
{
String test = "test";
//do something with test
}
{
String test = "test2"; 
//do something with test
}
```

In this case, variables with the same name are declared in separate scopes.

Comment: Its sole purpose may be to call `break`. Oh... and to assign literal labels.

Comment: So **@MouseEvent** that code inside that block will execute irrespective of any condition right?

Comment: Thank you **@default locale**

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here is just creating another *block* which creates a new scope. In a method, each pair of `{}` defines a scope. Variables defined in one scope cannot be used outside of that scope. For example, this if statement:

```
if (a == b) {
    int c = 10;
    // here I can access c
}
// but here, I cannot
```

Your `{}` without an `if` or `while` or any other control flow structures is also a scope. It will be executed unconditionally:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
} // prints 2 "Hello"s
```

The variables in these scopes also behave the same:

```
int a = 10;
{
    int b = 20;
    // can access a and b
}
// can only access a
```

How is this useful?

I think this is quite unnecessary and I have never used it in production code.